# Nginx config for hosting two nested websites

Tags: nginx

I am trying to write a Nginx config so that:

- If the URL is exactly `/Site/` it must serve `C:\Site\index.html`
- If the URL is `/Site/something/else` it must serve `C:\Site\something\else` (fallback to `index.html` if it doesn't exists) BUT only if `/something/` is different from `/api/` and `/dev/`
- If the URL is `/Site/api/something/else` it must redirect the exact request to another server `otherserver/api/something/else`
- If the URL is exactly `/Site/dev/` it must serve `C:\Site-Dev\index.html`
- If the URL is `/Site/dev/something/else` it must serve `C:\Site-Dev\something\else` (fallback to `index.html` if it doesn't exists) BUT only if `/something/` is different from `/api/`
- If the URL is `/Site/dev/api/something/else` it must redirect the exact request to another server `otherserverdev/api/something/else`

So the key point here is that:

- `/Site/` and `/Site/dev` are two different websites
- Each one has its own `.../api` endpoint

So far I wrote this config:

```
server {
    listen 19001;
    
    include mime.types;
    
    location ^~ /Site/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://otherserver;
    }

    location ^~ /Site/dev/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://otherserverdev;
    }

    location = /Site/ {
        root C:\Site;
        try_files /index.html =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/Site/(.*) {
        root C:\Site;
        try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
    }
    
    location = /Site/dev/ {
        root C:\Site-Dev;
        try_files /index.html =404;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/Site/dev/(.*) {
        root C:\Site-Dev;
        try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work at all, I'm getting `index.html` in every request and also `dev` and non`dev` are mixed up.

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Hi @edoedoedo have you found the answer? I need the same thing.

Comment: Yes I succeeded in writing a config that seems to work, I'll post that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a config which seems to do what I needed:

```
http {
    upstream loadbalancer {
        least_conn;
        server 127.0.0.1:xxx;
        ...
    }
    
    upstream loadbalancer_dev {
        least_conn;
        server 127.0.0.1:yyy;
        ...
    }

    server {
        listen zzz;
        
        include mime.types;
        
        location ^~ /Site/api/ {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
        }

        location ^~ /Site/dev/api/ {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer_dev;
        }
        
        # !!! Order of resolution matters (more specifics first)
        
        # Exact match
        location = /Site/dev/ {
            root C:/Site/site-dev;
            try_files /index.html =404;
        }
        
        # Regex match: trailing slash is omitted in order to be captured
        # by the regex when the uri is simply /Site/dev/
        # When falling back to /index.html, the previous exact match location is matched
        location ~* /Site/dev(.*) {
            root C:/Site/site-dev;
            try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
        }

        # Exact match
        location = /Site/ {
            root G:/Site/site;
            try_files /index.html =404;
        }

        # Regex match: trailing slash is omitted in order to be captured
        # by the regex when the uri is simply /Site/
        # When falling back to /index.html, the previous exact match location is matched
        location ~* /Site(.*) {
            root G:/Site/site;
            try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
        }

    }
}
```